# HXT ignoring HTML DTD, replacing it with XML DTD

Tags: haskell, doctype, hxt

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why HXT is replacing my DTD's. Firstly, here is my input file to be parsed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the output that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is a simplified version of the arrows I'm using:

```
start (App src dest) = runX $
                         readDocument [ withValidate no
                                      , withSubstDTDEntities no
                                      , withParseHTML yes
                                      --, withTagSoup
                                      ]
                                      src
                         >>>
                         this
                         >>>
                         writeDocument [ withIndent yes
                                       , withSubstDTDEntities no
                                       , withOutputHTML
                                       --, withOutputEncoding "UTF-8"
                                       ]
                                       dest
```

I apologize for the comments - I've been toying with different combinations of configs. I just can't seem to get HXT to *not* mess with DTDs, even with `withSubstDTDEntities no`, `withValidate no`, etc. I am getting a warning saying that HXT is ignoring my doctype declaration, but that's the only bit of insight I have. Can anyone please lend me a hand? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems

HXT only accepts one of the following three html doctypes

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
 "DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
```

Using one of these will get rid of the warning about ignoring the dtd.

Second, add the following option to writeDocument

```
withAddDefaultDTD yes
```