# Manipulating XML with HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, refactoring, hxt

From what I can tell, normal HXT seems to be more geared toward queries on XML moreso than XML AST refactoring. However, one of the HXT modules, `Data.Tree.NTree.Zippers.TypeDefs` seems to have some machinery for diving into a document and doing local work, instead of the more global arrows. However, I can't seem to get anything to work. This is a follow-up post to [my earlier HXT issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763855/hxt-ignoring-html-dtd-replacing-it-with-xml-dtd) - all the code is the same, except now `trans` is replacing `this`.

Here is the entry point to my program:

```
start :: App -> IO [XmlTree]
start (App src dest) = runX $
                         readDocument [
                                    --... some settings ...
                                      ]   
                                      src
                         >>>
                         trans
                         >>> 
                         writeDocument [
                                     --... some settings ...
                                       ]
                                       dest
```

And here is the module where `trans` is defined:

```
module Main.Internal where

import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

import Text.XML.HXT.DOM.XmlNode (mkText')
import Text.XML.HXT.Core hiding (addToTheRight)
import Data.Tree.NTree.Zipper.TypeDefs

trans :: IOSLA (XIOState s) XmlTree XmlTree
trans = arrL go
  where
    go :: XmlTree -> [XmlTree]
    go x = [fromNTZipper . manip . toNTZipper $ x]

unList :: [a] -> a
unList []    = error "dun goofed!"
unList (x:_) = x

manip = fromJust . (addToTheRight $ mkText' "bar")
      . fromJust . down
```

Finally, here is my input file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, why isn't "bar" anywhere to be found in my output? Shouldn't it appear right after `</html>`? Any help would, again, be wonderful :)

Comment: IIRC XML can only have one root node, can you put it inside the `<html>` tag instead for testing?

Comment: Actually my mistake, it should be inside the html node, right before `</html>`, but I'll try another level deeper just for kicks. Thank you!

Comment: the results are identical :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas seem to be solid and I'm not sure where you're wrong, but playing around with it I was able to generate the test code:

```
import Data.Tree.NTree.Zipper.TypeDefs
import Text.XML.HXT.Parser.HtmlParsec
import Text.XML.HXT.DOM.XmlNode
import Text.XML.HXT.DOM.TypeDefs
import Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs
import Control.Arrow.IOListArrow
import Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.WriteDocument
str = "<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>foo</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h1>foo</h1>\n  </body>\n</html>"

fromJust (Just x) = x

manip :: NTree XNode -> NTree XNode
manip x = fromNTZipper $ fromJust $
        down (toNTZipper x) >>= addToTheLeft (mkText "Boo!") >>= up

stringify = runIOLA $ writeDocumentToString []

main = do
    xs <- mapM stringify $ map manip $ parseHtmlDocument "" str
    putStrLn (show xs)
```

which outputs `[["\n  Boo!<head>\n    <title>foo</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h1>foo</h1>\n  </body>\n"]]`. I'm not actually sure what happened to the `<html>` element but `addToTheLeft` does exactly what it says it does. (I am using the `>>=` for the Maybe monad above).

I don't know if it's `trans` or `>>>` above that, but the `manip` you're doing seems like it should work.

**EDIT**: Notice that a lot of what I've written above **avoids** the idiomatic arrows which are central to HXT, which is probably why I'm getting some strange results. It looks from the package structure that importing `Text.XML.HXT.Core` is enough for generally reading strings and documents. The following works for me:

```
Prelude> let file = "<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>foo</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h1>foo</h1>\n  </body>\n</html>"
Prelude> :m +Text.XML.HXT.Core
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> let apply (arrows) str = head $ runLA (xshow $ hread >>> arrows) str
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> :t apply
apply :: LA XmlTree XmlTree -> String -> String
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> putStrLn $ apply (withNav $ moveDown >>> addToTheLeft (txt "bar") >>> moveUp) file
<html>bar
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

so those are the relevant functions. Notice that HXT already seems to do its `Maybe` stuff by clobbering XML trees in the list (of the `LA` list arrow) which do not satisfy a given predicate.

Comment: Ahh wow! I never used `up`, also I adore the binds! I had to do a few more jumps up the tree as well, to see the effects.

The strange thing is that these manipulations mess-up HXT's indenting, too.

Comment: Another strange thing is that arrow-based filters don't affect the NTZipper-style method of searching & inserting - that is to say if I first put `... >>> hasName "body" >>> trans >>> ...` before `trans`, it has __no effect__. It's really strange, I think we need a better xml _refactoring_ tool :/

Comment: Actually, scratch that, adding the additional filter is completely breaking the program (but still compiling) - it's not even sending any output text with `writeDocument`.

Comment: @AthanClark I've been able to get HXT to do exactly what you were doing with strings; see the above edit. If `writeDocument` stops outputting text then it's probably because of the last comment I made in there (clobbering XML trees). Basically, think of the type `a -> [b]`. You can use this type to do generic mapping (`gmap f x = [f x]`) and generic filtering (`gfilter f x = if f x then [x] else []`), and can compose such maps/filters with Kleisli composition in the List monad. Same here: most operations produce a list of successes; if you fail then that's represented by an empty list.